# Serverless Offline: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: yarnpkg, serverless, yarn-workspaces, serverless-offline

Not sure why this started happening but I have a very simple serverless app that was working, but now when I run `sls offline start` I get the error above. I have found the culprit and it is the `events` inside the functions.

Here is the `serverless.yml` file:

```yaml
service: hello-world-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  region: eu-east-1
  stage: dev

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

functions:
  hello-world:
    handler: handler.handle # required, handler set in AWS Lambda
    events:
      - http:
          path: hello-world
          method: get
          cors: true
```

Here is the `handler.js` file:

```js
module.exports.handle = async (event, ctx, cb) => {
  cb(null, {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: "hello world" })
  })
}
```

If I get rid of the `events` in the function `hello-world` everything works just fine with `sls offline start` except for the fact I can't actually hit the endpoint locally of course. I've tried making it a hard string by adding quotes but that did nothing.

EDIT: Turns out this happens when using `yarn workspaces`. If I put this in a `packages/my-serverless-app` structure and cd into the folder to run the `sls offline start` command this happens. If I remove it from the structure it works just fine.

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
events:
      - http:
          path: hello-world
          method: get
          cors: true
```

TO

```
events:
      - httpApi:
          path: hello-world
          method: get
```

And this should work!